# CSS "no-repeat" not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, content-management-system

Working with a bit of in-line CSS within a CMS (fun!). This chunk of code works as it should in Chrome and Firefox, the background image occurs just once. But when the page loads in IE 9, it's as if the no-repeat value is ignored and the background images repeats through the length of the div.

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin-top: -10px; background-image: url(http://.../uploadedImages/horizontal-rule-top.gif); background-position: 50% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; "><p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; color: rgb(228, 128, 28); padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 15px; font-size: 16px; ">
...</div>
```

Any advice would bemuch appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think IE's having trouble with the presence of the second `no-repeat`,  and, per spec, disregarding the rule it doesn't understand. The options that IE understands seem to be:

- `repeat-x`,
- `repeat-y`, and
- `no-repeat`.

If you amend your CSS to one of the above it should work.

Comment: It seems that [IE9 supports multiple backgrounds](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), but perhaps there are issues with its implementation that are manifesting here.

Comment: Yeah, I voted your answer up when I realised that it could, perhaps, be a problem with the multiple-background implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-repeat: no-repeat;` without the second value. I believe the two value syntax is part of the [CSS3 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-repeat) and may not be implemented by IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Try your background css  "background: url(http://.../uploadedImages/horizontal-rule-top.gif)  no-repeat 50% 0%;"

Answer (score 0):

Prova con:

background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat: repeat-y;